Bind9 rDNS for new ISP
We are a new ISP and one of our recent clients has an email server behind our public IP  and is requesting rDNS from us, We own a /21 prefix, and we give our client a /29 prefix for their services. I did some research and found out that We as an ISP are responsible to do rDNS but I simply can't find much information as to how this is setup.
I have created a bind9 server as a test and created a test zone with reverse zone which is working fine locally but how do I set this up without messing with the domain of our clients
I'll really appreciate your help.
Regards,
EDIT: After a while finally got it working, thank you for the guidance and information. Regards.

Ask your ISP to make your DNS responsive by using more than one DNS server or through the ISP's interface to input the entry.

There is no relationship between rDNS and the customer's regular DNS domains.
Reverse DNS for your IP address range is delegated through the IP address registry. For example, if you have an inetnum with RIPE you would create a domain object in the RIPE DB, named after the rDNS zone, and point its nserver: attribute to your nameservers that are hosting the zone – altogether very similar to delegating a regular DNS domain. Other RIRs (ARIN, APNIC etc) may have similar procedures.
domain:   5.168.192.in-addr.arpa
nserver:  ns1.example.net

Since you have a /21 you may need to repeat this for each of the eight /24 zones (z.y.x.ip-addr.arpa), or start with just the one /24 which has your customer.
Once the rDNS has been delegated to you, you can either directly set up PTR records for your customer or use various approaches to further delegate the /29 chunk to the customer's own nameservers. (A whole /24 is exactly at DNS 'dot' boundary so it can be delegated with just NS records, but below /24 it gets slightly ugly.)

Our IPs are with IAR Mexico, which we already point the /21 to a dns server, which for "new management" we no longer have" and also is pointing to a domain which is no longer in use, that is why I'm in the need to create a new server

Then just repeat the same procedure again. You said you've already set up the new nameserver. If you own the IP prefix, you next need to contact LACNIC to have the delegation updated to point to that new server – or have IAR Mexico do that on your behalf, whichever is more appropriate – and that's pretty much it?

Thank you for the link "various approaches" its been insightful, but reading all this got me thinking, in order to delegate the /29 to my customer I have to know where my customers domain is, right? so I can
domain:   5.168.192.in-addr.arpa
nserver:  ns1.customerdomain.net

Yes, if they want to host the DNS records on their own nameservers, then they have to tell you what/where those nameservers are. (It's entirely up to the customer whether they decide to use a nameserver related to their regular domain or not, so you can't automatically fill in "customer's domain" – you have to ask them for the nameservers (DNS servers) specifically.)

Note my example was for a whole /24 so it's fairly simple, there's only one way to do it – but since you're delegating a smaller part than a /24, it gets nonstandard and you'll need to choose one of the styles from that article and inform the customer so that they can configure their nameservers to match that.

"Yes, if they want to host the DNS records on their own nameservers, then they have to tell you what/where those nameservers are."
If their domain is hosted, ie. godaddy, hostgator, etc. do I have to redirect the /29 to the ns servers of said service?

What domain do you mean? Reverse DNS has nothing to do with the regular domains that you host on godaddy/hostgator.

Now I feel dumb, I think I'm getting overwhelm by all the information and getting the correct Idea, I bought a domain from Akky and added ns0.mydomain.com to a public IP but nothing happened the IP doesn't respond by name only if I ping directly the IP, so what I'm getting from this is that the reference domain>ip I did on Akky won't work unless I have a Public DNS Server with said IP so it can answer the ping by name (ns0.mydomain.com), am I correct?

once this work I can redirect my /21 to ns0.mydomain.com and then start creating the zones and rZones for the rDNS, am I correct? I know I haven't said this but I really appreciate your patience and help.

Not really sure where you added ns0.mydomain.com as there are two different places – did you do it in Akky's "Edit DNS records" section of some sort (i.e. where 'A' records are created), or did you do it in a "Nameserver" section? If it's the former, i.e. if Akky lets you directly edit A/TXT/etc. records, then Akky actually provides the public DNS server for your domain and nothing extra should be required for that. (Though you'll still need your own DNS server for the reverse zones, as Akky probably won't host those.)

On the other hand, if you did it in the "Nameserver" section, then yes, you told Akky that you'll be hosting the DNS records for your domain (i.e. the regular or "forward" zones) on your own nameserver instead of the provided one.

I would say that 'ping' really isn't the right tool to inspect DNS, though – if you want to make a DNS query, then use tools that are written to make a DNS query (dig, delv, nslookup, drill).

Ok, I did it as  nameserver as we don't have the DNS Service with them. so what is next for me is to publish the DNS server(Bind9 server) with the public IP so once someone tests the name ns0.mydomain.com my server responds and then have a working dns server to do forward or reverse DNS with?
